# Specific day of month such as 10th of muharram

Tags: java, android

```
double Suhoor;
this.Suhoor = fajr - 2;
if (this.calculationMethod.equalsIgnoreCase("UmmAlQuraUniv")) {
    try {
        HijriTime hijriTime = new HijriTime(Calendar.getInstance());
        if (hijriTime.ismuharram()) {
            this.Suhoor = fajr - 2;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        this.Suhoor = fajr - 2;
    }    
}
```

What is the correction in second if condition in this code to work in a specific day of month such as 10th of muharram.

In another way , what is required to modify the code to achieve the explanation in the above.

Answer (score 0):

To modify the code to only set the value of Suhoor to fajr - 2 on the 10th day of Muharram, you can modify the if condition as follows:

```
if (hijriTime.ismuharram() && hijriTime.getDayOfMonth() == 10) {
    this.Suhoor = fajr - 2;
}
```

This will check if the current day is in Muharram and if it is the 10th day of the month, and only set the value of Suhoor to fajr - 2 in that case. If the current day is not the 10th day of Muharram, the value of Suhoor will not be modified.

Note that this code assumes that the HijriTime class has a method called getDayOfMonth that returns the current day of the month in the Hijri calendar. It also assumes that the ismuharram method returns a boolean value indicating whether the current day is in Muharram or not. You may need to modify the code further if these assumptions are not correct.

Comment: this.day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

Comment: how to create method called getDayOfMonth

Comment: To create a method called getDayOfMonth that returns the day of the month for a given date, you can use the following steps:

Define a class that represents a date. This class should have at least the fields for the year, month, and day.
In the class, define a method called getDayOfMonth that returns the value of the day field.
Here's an example of how you can implement this in Java: public class Date {
  private int year;
  private int month;
  private int day;

  // constructor and other methods

  public int getDayOfMonth() {
    return this.day;
  }
}